# The tags [apache-jena] and [jena] should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

The tags [jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jena) and [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) seem to be about the same thing: https://jena.apache.org/

Proposal: Add [apache-jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-jena) as synonym of [jena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jena).

Comment: Hmm, the wiki posts of both the tags seem to differ. The [tag:jena] one points to http://www.openjena.org/ where as the other, [tag:apache-jena], points to the link you mentioned.

Comment: @BhargavRao: Both tag wikis link to https://jena.apache.org/ (as "homepage"). The one with the link to openjena.org (which is no longer active) seems to have this link for historic reasons, I guess … because Jena was not an Apache project right from the start.